# How to insert an ampersand conditionally in a SASS mixin?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

Below is some sass Im trying out, The css generated is correct, Im just trying to reduce my mixin duplication. The two mixins `genProps` and `genPropsAmp` are exactly the same except that the `Amp` mixin uses the `&` to prefix the rule with `&`. I tried to just add another var to the original mixin `$amp: false` and prefix my rule with an if so it became `@if $amp {&}.#{$class}-...` but that didnt work nor did trying to have it as an interpolation. Is there away of conditionaly placing the ampersand so I can just reuse the one mixin?

SASS:

```
$max_size: 0;
$sub_suffixes: '', 'q', 'h', 't';
$sub_divs: '', '.25', '.5', '.75';


@mixin genProps($class, $props, $val_prefix: r, $max_size: $max_size, $sub_suffixes: $sub_suffixes) {
    @for $i from 0 through $max_size {
        @each $sub_suffix in  $sub_suffixes {
            .#{$class}-#{$i}#{$sub_suffix} {
                @each $prop in $props {
                    #{$prop}: var(--#{$val_prefix}-#{$i}#{$sub_suffix});
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@mixin genPropsAmp($class, $props, $val_prefix: r, $max_size: $max_size, $sub_suffixes: $sub_suffixes) {
    @for $i from 0 through $max_size {
        @each $sub_suffix in  $sub_suffixes {
            &.#{$class}-#{$i}#{$sub_suffix} {
                @each $prop in $props {
                    #{$prop}: var(--#{$val_prefix}-#{$i}#{$sub_suffix});
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

.root{
    @include genProps(f, font-size, a);
    @include genPropsAmp(m, margin);
}
```

CSS:

```css
/* without amp */

.root .f-0 {font-size: var(--a-0);}
.root .f-0q {font-size: var(--a-0q);}
/*...*/

/* with amp */
.root.m-0 {margin: var(--r-0);}
.root.m-0q {margin: var(--r-0q);}
/*...*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator: `if($amp, "&", "")`

```
@mixin genProps($class, $props, $amp, $val_prefix: r, $max_size: $max_size, $sub_suffixes: $sub_suffixes) {
    @for $i from 0 through $max_size {
        @each $sub_suffix in  $sub_suffixes {
            #{if($amp, "&", "")}.#{$class}-#{$i}#{$sub_suffix} {
                @each $prop in $props {
                    #{$prop}: var(--#{$val_prefix}-#{$i}#{$sub_suffix});
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@mixin genProps($class, $props, $amp: false, $val_prefix: r, $max_size: $max_size, $sub_suffixes: $sub_suffixes) {
    @for $i from 0 through $max_size {
        @each $sub_suffix in  $sub_suffixes {
            @if $amp {
                &.#{$class}-#{$i}#{$sub_suffix} {
                    @each $prop in $props {
                        #{$prop}: var(--#{$val_prefix}-#{$i}#{$sub_suffix});
                    }
                }
            } @else {
                .#{$class}-#{$i}#{$sub_suffix} {
                    @each $prop in $props {
                        #{$prop}: var(--#{$val_prefix}-#{$i}#{$sub_suffix});
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

this is the best Iv got so far, not great as theres still a lot of duplication in the if elses but at least I only have one mixin now